# Error when quitting Excel and Logging Off

Tags: vba, excel, quit, logoff

I need some help with Excel VBA (2010 on windows 7).
What I'm trying to do is close Excel and then shutdown the pc.
The code I have is:

```
Declare Function ExitWindowsEx& Lib "User32" (ByVal uFlags As Long, ByVal dwReserved AS Long)
Global Const EWX_LOGOFF = 0
Global Const EWX_FORCE = 4

....Main Code Here ....

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.Quit

Action = ExitWindows(EWX_LOGOFF or EWX_FORCE, 0)
```

Intermittently I get the following error:

> Cannot Quit Microsoft Excel

The machine still logs off though, which is what I want so it's not a major issue.  I would just like to exit cleanly.  I've kept EWX_FORCE as I don't want to be prompted by windows.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Missing `DoEvents` after `Application.Quit` maybe? Include that so that Excel gets enough time to close else you will get an error. BTW this worked for me.

Also if any workbook/workbooks is/are opened then then it is a good idea to close it/them with/without saving code as you might loose data.

```
Public Declare Function ExitWindowsEx Lib "user32" (ByVal dwOptions As Long, _
ByVal dwReserved As Long) As Long

Public Const EWX_LogOff As Long = 0
Public Const EWX_SHUTDOWN As Long = 1
Public Const EWX_REBOOT As Long = 2
Public Const EWX_FORCE As Long = 4

Sub Sample()
    '
    '~~> Main Code Here
    '
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.Quit

    DoEvents

    ExitWindowsEx EWX_LogOff Or EWX_FORCE, &HFFFF
End Sub
```

Comment: When i add Do Events i am now not logged off.

Comment: The above code is tried and tested :) If you are not getting logged off then there is something which is preventing the system from logging off. And hence you were getting the error when you tried forcing a Log Off. `DoEvents` gives windows time to finish whatever it is doing before it can log off. You may also check for CPU activity when you issue the above command.

Comment: When I run this code, as soon as vba hits the `Application.Quit` line, Excel shuts down (as expected), consequently, the subsequent lines aren't processed.  The only way I can get this to work for me is to comment out the `Application.Quit` line, then the `DoEvents` and `ExitWindowsEx` lines do get processed.  What am I missing here?

Comment: What happens when you move `Application.Quit: DoEvents` after `ExitWindowsEx` line?

Comment: It seems to work OK then, but I'm not sure if ExitWindowsEx is closing Excel before it gets to the Application.Quit line.  Also, if I comment out the ExitWindowsEx line, and put a break point opposite DoEvents, the Application.Quit line shuts down Excel before getting to the DoEvents line.